# Custom maintenance page breaks module install process

Tags: theming, installation

I followed the steps on this page: https://drupal.org/node/195435 to style drupal's maintenance page.

All well until the moment I try installing another module (doesn't matter which one) via an url. It does not install the module and it just shows me my maintenance-page--offline.tpl file (-which should only be shown when the database is offline).

The problem also shows up when installing a new theme.
I'm running the latest drupal version (7.23).

Anyone having the same problem? What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your site set to offline?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the `$content` variable in the template even though you customized some texts in your template file. A sample would be:

```
<?php if ($content): ?>
<h1><?php print $content; ?></h1>
<?php else: ?>
<h1>Offline due to an unknown issue. Our engineers are working on it 24/7 to resolve this.</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Apparently, Drupal limits/locks access to the database during module/theme install, thus triggering the maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php. Take note that if you don't have the mentioned file, it will trigger maintenance-page.tpl.php.